# Can't figure out why my code won't render

Tags: reactjs, codepen

I am trying to build a simple app with React and I am using Codepen. I can't get my first component to render, even though it is a very basic code and it looks correct to me. I have included React, ReactDOM and Babel.
The html part of the project has a div with an id="root". The following code won't render anything and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
    <div>Hello World</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Can you provide the link to the codepen?

Are you calling `render` from ReactDOM?

Comment: Thanks! Here is the link: https://codepen.io/elnurad/pen/vYBagya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears that the scripts are in the wrong order. Make sure to load the React script before ReactDOM.

Changing them seems to fix the issue, [here's a forked version](https://codepen.io/Skovy/pen/vYBagWV)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Oh Wow! Thank you! Much Appreciated!

Comment: @EDonabedian please mark the correct answer as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is something wrong with your CDN links. 
I used these from https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html

https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js

https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js

And it worked fine.